# Mongoose error being returned as undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jasmine

I am trying to test my db connection with jasmine.

MongoClient is an object and is defined. However `err` returns undefined, naturally my test fails. Does Mongoose simply return undefined if there is no error?

Is there another way to check for the connection?

```
describe("MongoDB", function() {
it("is there a server running", function(next) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongoose');
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/panther_dev', function(err) {
        expect(err).toBe(null);
        next()
    });
});
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Your code isn't Mongoose code ... that's the native driver.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check your connection is to use [Connection#readyState](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-readyState). It returns one of four values which are:

- 0 = disconnected
- 1 = connected
- 2 = connecting
- 3 = disconnecting

So in your example, to test for a connection, it would look something like:

```
it("is there a server running", function(next) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongoose');
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/panther_dev', function(err) {
        expect(MongoClient.readyState).toBe(1);
        next();
    });
});
```